# Can't make sense of Strategy.exit expected behavior. How it really works?

Tags: pine-script

I'm having a hard time to understand `strategy.exit` behavior.
I run some short examples to try to make sense of if.

**Main questions about the behavior:**

1. When I set an exit, it will identify all entry orders that have active trades associated, or entry orders that is pending fulfillment with the same from_entry id (or all of them if no from_entry id is set for the exit order). Right?
2. It will affect in any way active entry orders placed while the exit still active, but place after the exit placement? If yes, exit become deactivated when the initial position are closed, or after all orders affected by exit are closed?
3. Can I place two `strategy.exit` orders affecting the same `from_entry`?
4. Can I place two `strategy.entry` orders with the same id -- it affect the `strategy.exit` execution in any way?

Next, I'm posting two small code examples that I can't understand what's happening.

### Problem 1: Exit appears to affect an arbitrary number of trades. Some created after it.

```pine
//@version=5
strategy("Exit test 1", overlay=true, pyramiding=10)
    
if bar_index == 1
   strategy.entry("buy1", strategy.long, qty = 10)
   strategy.exit("exit", from_entry = "buy1", qty = 2, loss = 100)
     
if bar_index >= 2
   strategy.entry("buy1", strategy.long, qty = 2)
```

[image: image results for problem 1]

**Problem 1:**  The Exit order is created on `bar_index == 1`, and become active on `bar_index == 2`.  Looks like the `exit` order only affects the three first trades. Two of them are created after the `exit`. Why it only affect this three trades here?

### Problem 2: Exit doesn't set `from_entry`.  If I don't set `exit`'s `from_entry` parameter, it started to execute on all trades.

```pine
//@version=5
strategy("Exit test 2", overlay=true, pyramiding=10)

if bar_index == 1
    strategy.entry("buy1", strategy.long, qty = 10)
    strategy.exit("exit", qty = 2, loss = 100)
 
if bar_index >= 2
    strategy.entry("buy1", strategy.long, qty = 3)
```

[image: Image results for problem 2]
**Problem 2:** Before, all trades had the same specified id `from_entry == "buy1"`. Why after I remove the `from_entry` parameter specification, just then it started to affect all trades?

Comment: Looks like a bug. If exit already closed part of the position, then new trades should not be affected, unless exit presists in a global scope (Called on a each bar). Directed it to the Pine team.

Comment: Oh, thanks. So exit should affect only pending orders or active trades placed at same time or before exit was called?

Comment: I had the impression it would affect all trade positions while the position was open.

Comment: it affects pending orders and active orders (depending of the id), in your example when it called just once, it will close part of the position (or whole if you will skip qty parameter), and then you will have to call it again. if you will put exit() in the main scope (out from `if` condition, then it will be called each bar, and it will close active orders, of will wait for the order to be filled, and then will close this ones

Comment: Turns out this is expected. Added new answer. In the future pine team will add some cases like this in the new manual for strategies.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour, when the `from_entry` argument is not specified - the `strategy.exit()`  "protects" all entries.
Since the pyramiding order is opened before the loss for the previous order is triggered, the `strategy.exit()` function itself is not deactivated due to the fact that the position is still open.
The function continues to apply to pyramiding positions that is still opened. The function will continue to close positions until there is no position left with any `entry_id`,
and only after that it is deactivated. After that, for new orders, the function must be called again.

Comment: I got this idea about `strategy.exit()` be kept alive while the position is opened. But can't understand why this behavior is not the same for `from_entry == 'buy1'`. More than that, it's not clear why the first example applies exit to just the first 3 trades... Can't see the position going flat there.